# Three js canvas blurry

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

How do I produce a better resolution? At the moment it is very blurry. I'm animating a cube that disassembles itself. This is using three.js. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

My js code:

```
canvas = document.getElementById( 'c' );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, antialias: true } );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 0);
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0xF3FFE2, size: 0.1, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 1, 0.1, 100 );
const plane = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );

const plane1 = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );

const plane2 = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );

plane1.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
plane2.rotation.y = Math.PI/2;


scene.add( plane );
scene.add(plane1);
scene.add(plane2);


camera.position.z = 60;


var toggle = false;
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    var t = Math.round(plane.scale.z * 100) / 100;
    if(t == 4){
        toggle = true;
    }
    if(t == 1){
        toggle = false;
    }

    if(!toggle){
        plane.scale.z += 0.01;
        plane1.scale.z += 0.01;
        plane2.scale.z += 0.01;
    }

    if(toggle){
        plane.scale.z -= 0.01;
        plane1.scale.z -= 0.01;
        plane2.scale.z -= 0.01;
    }

    plane.rotation.x += 0.005;
    plane.rotation.y += 0.005;
    plane1.rotation.x += 0.005;
    plane1.rotation.z -= 0.005;
    plane2.rotation.x += 0.005;
    plane2.rotation.y += 0.005;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/Saladmaster/697e5trx/

Thank you

Comment: Did you add width and height attributes to your canvas element in HTML?

Comment: I added it in css

Comment: Thats the problem then. The canvas attributes are the pixel dimensions available to the canvas. The CSS rule controls the presentation. Add the width and height to the element as attributes.

Comment: that fixed it, thank you!